# I can't use PsExec with python subprocess

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, remote-access, psexec

I want to connect remotely to computers and open a windows command line, but with a particularity: I do it with python for an automatism.
I usually use PsExec to be able to connect remotely manually but I noticed some problems: impossible to make tabs, the command line is limited and this is important for my python script.

I used subprocess to open a cmd in the background, and I execute multiple commands with the "&&" operation. My command looks like this:

```
command = "cd \folder\location && PsExec \<domainname> cmd && ipconfig"
```

Then I use subproccess :

```
process = sp.Popen('cmd /k "'+command+'"', stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True)
```

My problem arises at the execution of the ipconfig command, the result I get thanks to a print of

```
proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
```

shows me that the connection with PsExec was successful. **However the ipconfig show the configuration of the source computer and not the destination one.**

This means that the command works, but skips the PsExec layer.

If anyone has a solution to be able to use PsExec commands on a python script, or if you have an alternative I would be happy to hear them!

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've done a chunk of work, and I think you're pretty close with the Python end.

What I suggest you do is sort out the `psexec` stuff first before you fire it into Python.

There's *possibly* two things wrong with your `command` variable:

1. that `cmd` in the example isn't necessarily literal. The fact that `cmd` is actually something that you can run is a bit of a red herring.  You put the application that you want to run there, instead of `cmd`.
2. the `&&` separator is telling windows that this is a new command. So it runs `ipconfig` after the `psexec` command has exited. (Just like it runs `psexec` after the `cd` command has completed).

So what I think you need for command is
`command = "cd \folder\location && PsExec <domainname> ipconfig`

Because `ipconfig` is one of those utilities that's generally on the system path so you don't need to provide full path to it.

What I'd do though, is open a Windows command shell and just tweak the `PsExec` command until you see the `ipconfig` of your destination machine.

Then you can go back to Python and plug in your variables.

Comment: It's good to know that you understood what I wanted to do :)
Thank you for your quick response!
I have indeed already thought about running a simple command for "ipconfig" for example. But in reality it's only a test because I have multiple commands to do in a row (cd and run for particular files ect). That's why I would need the && separator that would fit in the PsExec.
The problem here is that I don't have the result of the ipconfig, I only have this:

Comment: The command :
`command = "cd C:\\deploiement\\psremoting\\ && PsExec.exe \<domainname>+" ipconfig /all"`

I would like to be able to see the result of the command and have the ability to perform multiple commands.

I don't know if I'm doing it right, do you have any ideas?